# Getting Helper errors despite defining helpers in Data

Tags: menu

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_VMR_Customreports_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /Volumes/Apache/mage/app/Mage.php on line 546

where VMR is my namespace and Customreports is my module name.

Now usually I fix this by putting

```
class Mage_VMR_Customreports_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

in /Helper/Data.php  but that isn't fixing it this time.

I have noticed that the error changes when I change the menu definition in config.xml

which is currently:

```
<menu>
    <vmr_menu>
        <children>
            <customreports translate="title" module="VMR_Customreports">
                ...
            </customreports>
        </children>
    </vmr_menu>
</menu>
```

My config.xml helper stuff is:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <customreports>
            <class>VMR_Customreports_Helper</class>
        </customreports>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

and my Data.php is:

```
<?php

class VMR_Customreports_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}

class Mage_VMR_Customreports_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: FYI, when I remove ' translate="title" module="VMR_Customreports" ' from the menu definition, it works fine

Comment: but then I get errors elsewhere

Comment: Yeah so apparently getting rid of any use of Mage::helper(My_Module) 'fixes' it, but I need to use my helper. :(

Comment: Also, I have the <helpers> block defined in <globals> as I should

Comment: Please post the helper declaration in config.xml and also the example of how you call your helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `module` attribute must match your class group under `global/helpers` xpath (i.e. `customreports`):

```
<menu>
    <vmr_menu>
        <children>
            <customreports translate="title" module="customreports">
            ...
            </customreports>
        </children>
    </vmr_menu>
</menu>
```

Think of the argument from the `module` attribute as being used to grab the specified helper class singleton (because it is - see [`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu::_getHelperValue()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php#L119)):

```
/**
 * Retrieve Title value for menu node
 *
 * @param Varien_Simplexml_Element $child
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getHelperValue(Varien_Simplexml_Element $child)
{
    $helperName         = 'adminhtml';
    $titleNodeName      = 'title';
    $childAttributes    = $child->attributes();
    if (isset($childAttributes['module'])) {
        $helperName     = (string)$childAttributes['module'];
    }

    return Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$child->$titleNodeName);
}
```

And don't forget that when there is no slash present in the factory argument for helpers, `/data` is assumed in `Mage_Core_Model::getHelperClassName()`, i.e. `Mage::getHelper('customreports')` is a.k.a `Mage::getHelper('customreports/data')`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might just have an extra "Mage_" at the start of your helper class name.
So, Magento would be looking in YourRoot/app/code/YourCodePool/**Mage**/VMR/Customreports/Helper/